# Flash Media Server, HLS and FLV

Tags: ios, streaming, flv, rtmp, flash-media-server

I use RTMP to stream from my iPhone to my server with FMS. I followed some tutorials and now I have the flv playback file in /webroot/live_recorded. 
What i want to do is the following. 
1) Stream from iPhone to server using RTMP  : DONE
2) Stream back to iPhone using HLS : I don't understand the docs and i read hundreds of threafds but none helped me. I would like the user to read the stream from the beginning, as it is stored on my server. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm actually not about FMS.. i work with Wowza and i suppose you'll need something like nDVR feature or have someone write special module for you that will split live stream into small recordings, and so you'll need to play playlist of such recorded files from your iPhone.

hopefully someone will recommend true solution, not just some assumptions :)

Comment: Thanks, as you are the only one, your answer is awesomely appreciated.